# Problema com conexão Mysql no C#

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin

Criei uma classe de conexão para minha aplicação no Xamarin, mas toda vez que tento conectar lança essa exceção:

> "The type initializer for
>   'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an
>   exception"

Segue o código de exemplo

```
private static MySqlConnection _conexao = new MySqlConnection();

public void Conectar()
{
      _conexao.ConnectionString = string.Format("server={0};database={1};uid={2}; pwd={3}", Server, Database, Usuario, Senha);
      try
      {
          _conexao.Open();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
      }
 }
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser? As informações passadas de servidor,  database, usuario e senha, estão corretas, já conferi.

Comment: Vá em *Project* → *Properties* → *Debug* e marque a opção *Enable native code debbuging*. Execute o programa novamente.

Comment: No código fonte, parece que é [essa linha](https://github.com/pdonald/mysql-connector-net/blob/master/Source/MySql.Data/Replication/ReplicationManager.cs#L86) que lança a exceção.

Comment: Não encontrei está opção no meu VS, não tem uma aba Debug.

Answer (score 3):

Veja, pode ser que exista um problema de conceito ai. Não é seguro acessar um banco de dados diretamente de um app, por isso criamos um barramento de Api que expõe informações e tem uma camada de segurança, seja ela um JWT, oAuth, etc.
A não ser que você tenha total controle do ambiente do seu App, evite isso.

Sobre o erro em si, se o seu server estiver na mesma máquina, algo como Localhost, possivelmente não funcionará, o emulador não identifica localhost como uma porta válida. 
Cada emulador trada de um jeito diferente, o Genymotion por exemplo, acessa o Localhost pelo ip 10.0.3.2, o emuladro default acessa via 10.0.2.2